# Indexing multiple documents

Tags: solr, spark-streaming, solrj

I encounter errors while trying to index multiple documents in `solr` with `spark-streaming` using `solrj`. Each record I parse and index, each `micro-batch`.

In the code below, the first method (tagged) functions as expected. The second method (tagged) does not do anything, it does not event fail.

In the first option, I index a record for each partition; useless, but functional.
In the second method, I convert each element of my partitions into a document and then try to index each of them, but fail: no records are showing in the collection.

I use `solrj 4.10` and `spark-2.2.1`.

```scala
//method 1
myDStream.foreachRDD { rdd => rdd.foreachPartition { records =>

  val solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(collectionUrl)

  val document = new SolrInputDocument()
  document.addField("key", "someValue")
  ...

  solrServer.add(document)
  solrServer.commit()
}}
```

```scala
//method 2
myDStream.foreachRDD { rdd => rdd.foreachPartition { records =>

  val solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(collectionUrl)

  records.map { record =>

    val document = new SolrInputDocument()
    document.addField("key", record.key)
    ...

    solrServer.add(document)
    solrServer.commit()
  }
}}
```

I would like to understand why the second method does not work and find a solution to multiple documents indexing.

Comment: You don't use `records` in the method 1, why ? It would be interesting to see what it looks like. You may need to edit your post and add a `record` debug output from the `map function`, it should help.

Comment: The Solr log should show you each request and the result from it - start by seeing that you're _actually adding_ the documents to Solr. You might have to change the log level to `INFO` in the web interface to see those log entries.

Comment: @EricLavault You were right, the `records` is empty... But this is strange because I `myDStream.print()` just before my loop, and it shows full fledged records printed. Have you ever encountered that behaviour before?

Comment: Well, yes I think this is an *iterator* issue, when iterating over an object you need to use the correct iterator to properly access the objects and methods in the collection. Here it seems `rdd.foreachPartition` is not working for what you need to achieve.

Comment: Had stay with `rdd`s. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to process the records through `rdd`s:

```scala
myDStream.foreachRDD { rdd => rdd.foreach { record =>

  val solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(collectionUrl)

  val document = new SolrInputDocument()
  document.addField("key", record.key)
  ...

  solrServer.add(document)
  solrServer.commit()
}}
```

See EricLavault's comment above for more information about the issue source suspicion.

Comment: But this is ugly: it creates a `HttpSolrServer` for each record... Is there no better way?